# How to read DICOM string value with backslash (VR=LO, Value="0.4323\0.2325")?

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

Our C++ software use ITK to write DICOM files. In it we have a Private Tag with `LO` (Long String) as `VR` and 2 decimal values as value like `0.3234\0.34223`.

The `LO` choice is inherent to ITK.

In other java application, I use dcm4che3 to read/write them. Since it respects the DICOM protocol, backslash are forbidden, and dcm4che interpret the value as `"0.3234"` and never reach the second value.

All DICOM viewer applications I use can display this value.

So my question is: Is there a trick in dcm4che to read this complete value as a string `"0.3234\0.34223"` despite the presence of a backslash?

Below, the code I use:

```
     public DicomInfo uploadFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException, ParseException {

       DicomInfo infos = new DicomInfo();

       Attributes attrs = readDicomAttributes(file);
       infos.setTags(toAttributesObject(attrs).toString());
    }

    private static JsonObject toAttributesObject(Attributes targetSeriesAttrs) 
    {
       StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
       JsonGenerator gen = Json.createGenerator(strWriter);
       JSONWriter writer = new JSONWriter(gen);
       writer.write(targetSeriesAttrs);
       gen.flush();
       gen.close();
       return Json.createReader(new 
          StringReader(strWriter.toString())).readObject();
  }
  
  public Attributes readDicomAttributes(MultipartFile file) throws IOException 
  {
    DicomInputStream dis = new DicomInputStream(file.getInputStream());
    Attributes dataSet = dis.readDataset(-1, Tag.PixelData);
    Attributes fmi = dis.readFileMetaInformation();
    dis.close();

    fmi.addAll(dataSet);

    return fmi;
  }
```

In the JSON I get for this tag:

```
\"00110013\":{\"vr\":\"LO\",\"Value\":[\"0.4323\"]},
```

As you can see it is LO and the second part is already lost.

The method I use to get the specific attribute:

```
attr.getStrings(0x00110013)
```

send back a table with only one value, 0.4323.

The problem happens during the readDataSet function.

When I open tags with software like free dicom viewer, I have the complete data, so data is here.

---

Ok I found the source of the problem... It is the `addAll` `fmi.addAll(dataSet);`

In dataSet, `getStrings` works perfectly. In `fmi` after `addAll`, the attributes lost the second value.

So my problem is to solve this `addAll` issue now: [dcm4che3 java lib: Attributes.addAll method seems to lost multiple LO values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63269682/5704707)

Comment: Backslash is not forbidden, I guess that you somehow have to tell dcm4che that your private attribute has a value multiplicity of 2. I do not know how to do this exactly, but usually this configuration is referred to as "private dictionary"

Comment: in LO backslash should not be used, cf documentation, so even getStringS doesn't work. And I can't modify the VR.

Comment: I think the only solution is to forget dcm4che and use ITK impl in java ...

Comment: I haven't used dcm4che, but a quick look at the sources shows that `StringValueType.getStrings()` does the right thing, e.g. splits the tag content by the '\' delimiter and returns the strings. Can you show the code you use to read the tag contents?

Comment: I just edit to put my code and the results

Comment: and precision, it is dcm4che3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this problem is to write

```
dataSet.addAll(fmi);
return dataSet;
```

instead of

```
fmi.AddAll(dataSet);
return fmi;
```

since the addAll methods lost multiple values of private LO

Answer (score 1):

See answer from Paolo, and please believe us that the backslash is not a violation of the VR. Like he said, the attribute is *2-dimensional*, i.e. it has *two values of VR LO which are separated by the backslash*.

I know a bit about the dcm4che project and the people behind it, and it is nearly unthinkable to me that it is generally incapable of handling this.

I strongly suspect that your problem is related to the fact that your attribute is *private*. That is, without any additional information to the tag and its value, dcm4che (and any other product) can never know that the attribute's value is encoded as VR LO (Long String).

The default transfer syntax in DICOM is Implicit Little Endian. This means, that the dataset does not convey an *explicit* information about the VR of the attributes in the dataset. This information is *implicitly* encoded by the Tag of the attribute, and the data dictionary (DICOM Part 6) must be used to look up the tag and obtain the corresponding VR. Obvioulsy this only works for well-known DICOM tags defined in the standard and fails for private ones.

So one option is to try **encoding the dataset in Explicit Little Endian**, which means that the VR is part of the attribute's encoding in the dataset. I would expect this to be sufficient.

Mature toolkits (like dcm4che) allow for **extending the data dictionary by configuration**, that is, you can extend the "official" data dictionary used by the tookit with your custom tag definitions - including the VR. So the tag can be looked up in the case that the VR is not explicitly given in the dataset itself.

Again, I am not an expert for dcm4che, but a quick search at google for "dcm4che private dictionary" yields [this promising link](https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/d2/pages/1835048/Adding+private+tags+to+the+dictionary).

I am more than confident that you can solve the problem in dcm4che and that you do not have to migrate to a different toolkit.

Comment: In my understanding, **encoding the dataset in Explicit Little Endian** should do the job; unfortunately, OP did not explicitly mentioned it in question or comment whether they tried this. Hope they try it and come up with output.

Comment: @AmitJoshi - I actually assumed that they did encode it as Explicit Little Endian, otherwise they won't know the VR - but you are right, that may be exactly the problem. Otherwise completely agree with kritzel_sw.

Answer (score 0):

LO can have multiple values separated by a backslash.

The DICOM standard says that in the VR "LO" the backslash cannot be used in values because it is used to separate the different elements.

In VRs that don't allow multiple elements then the backslash can be used in values.

So dcm4che is wrong here.